# Microsoft Bot DirectLineClient v 3.0

Tags: bots, skype, skype-bots

I have embedded a Skype chat control in my ASP.NET application, and configured it to use a data-bot-id.

```
<div class="skype-button bubble"
     data-bot-id="xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx"
     data-color="#00cc33"
     data-show-header="true"
     data-can-upload-file="false"
     data-can-close="true"
     data-can-collapse="true"
     data-text="MyBot">
</div>
```

Now, trying to use DirectLineClient in my ASP.NET code behind to monitor messages posted by any user(s) on the Skype bot.

I receive a compiler error executing the below line -

```
DirectLineClient client = new DirectLineClient(m_directLineSecret);
```

Compiler Error Message: CS0012: The type 'DelegatingHandler' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

I have included Microsoft.Bot.Connector.DirectLine.